# Some characters not working in HTML email VB

Tags: html, vb.net

I an application that generates and sends a HTML email to customers. This works with the exception that some characters namely ( )  &  *  %   $  #  @  ! ~  ;  _ = + /   -  ? ' does not work. The following is the code that I use. Please suggest how I can allow these special characters in my HTML email.

```
Sub subHtmlEmail(ByVal strAddresseeEmail As String, ByVal strGroup As String)
    Try
        Dim strTo, strFrom, strBody, strSubject, strBcc As String
        Dim boolHtml As Boolean = True ' set the body content to plain text(false) or HTML(true)
        strFrom = "sales@mycompany.com"
        strTo = strAddresseeEmail ' ; Separates emails
        strBcc = "" ' ; Separates emails

        strSubject = txtEmailSubject.Text

        strBody = "<html><head></head><body>"
        strBody = strBody & "<img src=cid:Logo>"
        strBody &= "<br><br>"


        strBody &= "Dear " & clsGroupCustomers.RetrieveAddressee(strAddresseeEmail, strGroup) & ",<br><br>"

        Dim strLines As String() = txtBody.Text.Split(New [Char]() {CChar(vbCrLf)})
        For Each strLine As String In strLines
            strBody &= strLine & "<br>"
        Next

        strBody &= "<br><br>"

        Dim strFooterLines As String() = txtFooter.Text.Split(New [Char]() {CChar(vbCrLf)})
        For Each strFooterLine As String In strFooterLines
            strBody &= strFooterLine & "<br>"
        Next

        HTMLView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(strBody, Nothing, "text/html")

        strBody &= "</body></html>"

        subEmail(strFrom, strTo, strBcc, strSubject, strBody, boolHtml, strAddresseeEmail)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Cursor = Cursors.Default
        MsgBox("An error has occurred in your application while attempting to create the email." & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Description: " & ex.Message & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "Please contact your System Administrator.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Application Error")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML these characters should be encoded. For example: & (Ampersand) should be emitted as `&amp;`

In .NET you can call `HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(myStringValue)` to do this automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks mate. I just came across      System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myStringValue), that works too. :)